# How to update a packaging made in an original design to the one previously used in another design Proteus

Tags: proteus, footprint, packages, model

I'm working in a design in Proteus where I'm making a multi-board design. I've made a previous design where I've made a PCB model of an ESP8266-ESP01 but initially I was mistaken with the pin numbering of the model.

I realized that and after updating the packaging and the model itself in the original design, then the next step was to update that model in the final multi-board design. However what I did didn't work at all and the first wrong model is still appearing in the design.

Labcenter clearly says this in the help about editing the packages:

> Remember that all design files carry with them their own copies of the library parts that they use. Consequently, changing a part in a library will not directly change any designs that make use of it. To effect such a change, you must load the drawing into ISIS and use the Pick command from the Library menu to effect a replace operation.

What I couldn't do was the part of "you must load the drawing into ISIS and use the Pick command from the library menu to effect a replace operation" because I don't know how to do it.

The device appears updated in my new design, as you can see in the following image:

[image: Device updated]

But when I place the device and go to place the footprint in Ares, then the pin numbering is shown with the old footprint like is seen in the following image:

[image]

How can I solve this?

NOTE: I know that I can simply create a new project and insert the new instance, but I'd like to know how to insert the model in the right way.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Usually deleting the part from the schematic then loading in the new part does it for me. If that doesn't work, then delete the part from the pick menu on ISIS and then select it again from the parts list. That should hopefully work. What version of Proteus do you use? I usually get a prompt after editing a component to update all instances of it in a design

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tried both options without success, Right now I've created a new project to put the correct model. I've done that by exporting a Project Clip without the model of the ESP8266 and then inserting the component into the new Project. I'm using Proteus 8.6 SP2

Comment: that's very strange. That should have worked. I would try posting a query on the Labcenter forums and see if they can explain it, or tell you  how to fix it. There is also the technical support email you can contact. I have found them to be quite good in the past

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it